# Wix installer registry keys not getting created in Wow64 node

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, registry, procrun

I have a 64 bit machine in which I need to install a Windows service. This service was created using Apache procrun, therefore I need to create certain registry keys. These should go into the wow64 node as I expect them to, but they get created in HKLM/SOFTWARES instread of HKLM/SOFTWARE/Wow64 node. Below is my Product.wxs file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Product Id="*" Name="DummyInstaller" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Bryan" UpgradeCode="94D1BC64-7CC1-45DA-BD5F-8ED40980E75C">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <Property Id="JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION64">
      <RegistrySearch Id="JRE_CURRENT_VERSION_REGSEARCH64" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" Name="CurrentVersion" Type="raw" Win64="yes" />
    </Property>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="DummyInstaller" Level="1" >
      <!--<ComponentGroupRef Id="NewFilesGroup" />-->
      <ComponentRef Id="REGISTRY_A" />
      <ComponentRef Id="PROCRUN.EXE"/>
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="DummyDir" Name="DummyInstaller">
          <!--<Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="MosquittoNew" />-->
          <Directory Id="SERVERDIR" Name="UpdaterService" >
            <Component Id="REGISTRY_A" DiskId="1" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\UpdaterService\Parameters\Java" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Classpath" Value="E:\Service\Update_Service-1.0.jar" KeyPath="yes" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Jvm"     Value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll" />
                <RegistryValue Type="multiString" Action="append" Name="Options">
                  <MultiStringValue Type="multiString" Name="Options" Action="append">-Duser.language=en</MultiStringValue>
                  <MultiStringValue Type="multiString" Name="Options" Action="append">-Duser.region=US</MultiStringValue>
                </RegistryValue>
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="JvmMs" Value="256" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="JvmMx" Value="1024" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="JvmSs" Value="4000" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\UpdaterService\Parameters\Log" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Path" Value="c:\logs" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Level" Value="Error" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Prefix" Value="UpdaterService" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="StdError" Value="c:\logs\stderr.txt" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="StdOutput" Value="c:\logs\stdout.txt" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\UpdaterService\Parameters\Start" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Mode" Value="jvm" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="com.kohls.kube.services.updater.UpdaterServiceMain" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Params" Value="start" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\UpdaterService\Parameters\Stop" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Mode" Value="jvm" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="com.kohls.kube.services.updater.UpdaterServiceMain" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Method" Value="stop" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Params" Value="stop" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="StdOutput" Value="auto" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UpdaterService" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Description" Value="Kube updater service performing updates and installation" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DisplayName" Value="UpdaterService" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ImagePath" Value="E:\Service\prunsrv.exe.exe //RS//UpdaterService" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DependsOnService" Value="Tcpip Afd" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ObjectName" Value="LocalSystem" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="ErrorControl" Value="1" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Start" Value="2" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Type" Value="16" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UpdaterService\Parameters" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Test" Value="Pass" />
              </RegistryKey>
            </Component>


            <Component Id="PROCRUN.EXE" DiskId="1" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
              <!-- this is the renamed procrun 64 bit executable -->
              <File Id="prunsrv.exe" Name="prunsrv.exe" Source="E:\Service\prunsrv.exe" />
              <ServiceInstall Id="PROCRUN" Type="ownProcess" Name="UpdaterService" DisplayName="UpdaterService" Description="Kube 2.0 Updater Service" Start="auto" Account="LocalService"  ErrorControl="normal" Arguments=" //RS//UpdaterService" />
              <ServiceControl Id="StartPRUNSRV" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="UpdaterService" Wait="no" />
            </Component>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>


</Wix>
```

I have specified the Win64=yes parameter. For the WIX setup project, I also specified "-arch x64" under project settings->Toolset->Additional Parameters. Still I get the registry keys created in normal HKLM/SOFTWARES and not in the wow64 node. Why is this happening? Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For keys that need to go to the 32 bit registry location (Wow6432Node) in a 64-bit installer you need to specify Win64="no"

It is a little confusing but Wow6432Node is actually the 32-bit portion of the registry on a 64-bit machine and NOT the 64-bit portion.

Comment: Yes, WOW64 is read as (32-bit) Windows on 64-bit Windows. (Machine is not relevant as long as it can run 64-bit Windows.)